# Copy to clipboard in SAP using UiPath

Tags: uipath, sap-gui

I am using UiPath to open SAP GUI transaction and create txt file. Robot will open transaction, set filters and copy desired column to clipboard to use it in another transaction.

Problem is I need to apply filter and then copy the column to clipboard.

I can do trick:

```
Set Filter... -> F4, CTRL+Y CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN -> CTRL+C
```

But this will not apply filter before copy happens.

SAP table has around 3.8k rows and looks like this:

```
Criterium   Transaction
CLOSED  1
CLOSED  2
CREATED 3
CREATED 4
OPEN    5
```

I have access only to SAP GUI front end of SAP system.
Any ideas?

Comment: sorry for asking but there is no possibility to export to excel or something like that?

Comment: Yes it is possible to export data to excel file, but I do not want to create additional files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem.

It is possible to view the data otherwise than "Grid". Additionaly by changing layout data can be filtered, so less columns will be shown and SAP will be able to show desired columns as "Excel inbuild" view. From there it is possible to copy to clipboard without creating extra files.